# Format HTML Text proper

Tags: html, css

How can I format my text with html and CSS to get something like this:

```
Animals: cat, dog, mouse,
         lion, tiger
```

---

I tried this but it doesnt´t work.

```css
.column {
 width: 300px;
}

.fat-text {
 font-weight: bold;
 display: inline-block;
}

.listing {
 border: 1px solid red;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="column">
  <span class="fat-text">Animals: </span><span class="listing">cat, dog, mouse, elephant, tiger, lion, penguin, lama, wolf</span>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is something I'd be using a table for...looks like tabluar data, smells like tabular data...use a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define width your `.listing`  and define `vertical-align:top` as like this

```css
.column {
 width: 300px;
}

.fat-text {
 font-weight: bold;
 display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;
}

.listing {
 border: 1px solid red;
 display: inline-block;    width: 230px;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="column">
  <span class="fat-text">Animals: </span><span class="listing">cat, dog, mouse, elephant, tiger, lion, penguin, lama, wolf</span>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the css  for class listing added two property:

```
position: absolute;
    width: 113px; in case if you want fixed width
```

```css
.column {
 width: 300px;
}

.fat-text {
 font-weight: bold;
 display: inline-block;
}

.listing {
 border: 1px solid red;
position: absolute;
width: 113px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="column">
  <span class="fat-text">Animals: </span><span class="listing">cat, dog, mouse, elephant, tiger, lion, penguin, lama, wolf</span>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use flexbox for this:

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
              .column {
                width: 300px;
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -webkit-flex;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
                -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
                    -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
                        flex-flow: row nowrap;
              }
              .fat-text {
                font-weight: bold;
                margin-right: 8px;
              }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div class="column">
            <span class="fat-text">Animals: </span><span class="listing">cat, dog, mouse, elephant, tiger, lion, penguin, lama, wolf</span>
          </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```